# If function parameter is empty is there a way to pass ...rest of values to that parameter?

Tags: javascript

If function parameter is empty is there a way to pass ...rest of the destructured values to that parameter with spread operator?

For an example:

```
const obj = {
  /* param: {
        a: 2,
        b: 3
  }, */
  c: 1,
  d: 3
}

const fun = ({ param = ...rest}) => {
    console.log(param);
};


fun(obj);
```

In this case param is `"undefined"` and i would like to get the rest of the `obj` assign to the param `{c:1, d:3}`

In case when param is defined, I would like to have param data `{a:2, b:3}`

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary operator in the function parameter section to determine which properties to log:

```js
const obj = {
  /*param: {
        a: 2,
        b: 3
  },*/
  c: 1,
  d: 3
}
  
const fun = (args = obj.param ? obj.param : obj) => {
  console.log(args)
}

fun(obj)
```

Comment: I am looking for solution to do it inside the function parameters.

Comment: @MilanMilosev see my edit. You can just move the ternary operator to inside the param section.